# Jenkins API to update library configuration

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to update a library in "Configuration" we use in Jenkins through Python, but do not see any way to do this through Jenkins API. Is there a way to update the version to `1.1.0` via Jenkins API?

[image]

Comment: How are you using Jenkins API through Python? I could possibly help with Groovy code, but I'm not sure this could be translated to Python.

Comment: @zett42 Actually Groovy would be perfect. Our pipeline is written in Groovy. Do you know how to do this in Groovy?

Comment: Not yet, but there is a good chance I'll find it. I've done quite much through the API.

Comment: I couldn't find a Groovy way. In theory one should be able to get property `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.FolderLibraries` from the folder, but it returned `null`. Alternatively you could edit the config file XML through REST API: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218353308-How-to-update-job-config-files-using-the-REST-API-and-cURL-?page=69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are ok with using a groovy script to configure the library version, you can use the following script to set the default version of an **Global existing library**:

```grrovy
def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def globalLibraryDescriptor = jenkins.getDescriptor("org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.GlobalLibraries")
def config = globalLibraryDescriptor.getLibraries().find {
   it.name == '1.1.0' // Find your existing library by name
}
config.setDefaultVersion("THE_NEW_VERION")  // Update the default version value
```

If you also want to create library configurations in the global settings via API you can use the [following script](https://github.com/cloudbees/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/createGlobalSharedLibrary.groovy) as a usage example for the groovy API.

If you want to configure a **Folder** level **Existing library** you can use the following code:

```groovy
def jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance()
def folderLibrary = jenkins.getItem("FOLDER_NAME").getProperties().find {it.class =~ 'FolderLibraries'}
def config = folderLibrary.getLibraries().find {
   it.name == '1.1.0' // Find your existing library by name
}
config.setDefaultVersion("THE_NEW_VERION")  // Update the default version value
```

Comment: Thanks for the example!! This is very helpful, but we are trying to do this with a shared pipeline library associated with a particular folder, not a global library. Any idea how that would be set?

Comment: @jipot i have updated the answer with code for configuring a folder level library, basically just replace the second line with `jenkins.getItem("MyFolder").getProperties().find {it.class == 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.FolderLibraries'}` to get the folder level library config.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: We got it to work with Shared Library using the following code (if anyone runs into needing this to work):

```
for (LibraryResolver resolver : ExtensionList.lookup(LibraryResolver.class)) {
    for (LibraryConfiguration cfg : resolver.forJob(currentBuild.rawBuild.getParent(), [:])) {
        if (cfg.getName == libraryName){
            cfg.setDefaultVersion("1.1.0")
        }
    }
}
```